# Make dynamic redirection with dynamic sub domain

Tags: redirect, subdomain, wildcard, dynamic

**it is possible to make dynamic redirection with dynamic sub domain?**

that is to say that I have a domain with redirection *.domain.com, to my server-1 but I'd like:

- a1.domain.com -> server-1
- b1.domain.com -> server-1
- c1.domain.com -> server-1
- ...
- a2.domain.com -> server-2
- b2.domain.com -> server-2
- c2.domain.com -> server-2
- ...

I want to store the sub-domains with the server to which it belongs, to add as I want.
My 1-server is a Web hosting services
my server-2 is an iis server

**Is it possible to do this in php?**

thank's

Comment: This should be done in DNS.

Comment: How ? I have a domain with *.domain.com A record to my server-1 (Web hosting) and I have a Windows Server 2012 R2